# Where can I get this type of 'wood paneling'/'siding'/(name?)

Tags: siding, fascia

Sorry about my ignorance here but I don't know what to call this stuff.  I have a few wood (Pretty sure it's wood) boards that have falling off the side of the area that supports my deck.  Questions:

1. What are these boards called?
2. Is it possible to order it anywhere so I can replace it?

[image]
[image]

We also have some fascia(?) or molding that has come off (looks like the previous owner installed the gutters poorly.  So not sure I can get this fascia board at the same place? THANKS!

[image]

Comment: could be Hardieplank

Comment: @Jasen I am almost positive you are right on the siding. Trim by roof and gutter likely original wood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generically, that's called "Ship Lap" siding. What it is made of is another aspect; it could be wood such as cedar or redwood, it could be pressboard, it could be vinyl or even aluminum made to look like wood. You should be able to tell if it's vinyl or metal by tapping on it. If it's pressboard, you would be able, if you look long enough, to see repeating grain patterns, something that never happens with real wood.

That fascia / molding and the roof joint needs some professional attention in my opinion. That's a tough spot for a typical DYI project and getting it wrong can leave you with some serious water damage.

Comment: Just "lap siding". Shiplap has a rabbet on the edges so every board lays flat rather than sitting at a slight angle like the pictured lap siding.

Comment: You guys are the best.  The previous owner(s?) have been known to frequent the local Home Depot and get absolutely everything there.  I think there's a very good chance this is the one:  https://www.homedepot.com/p/James-Hardie-HardiePlank-HZ10-5-16-in-x-8-25-in-x-144-in-Fiber-Cement-Select-Cedarmill-Lap-Siding-215518/100064049